# Find the numbers that can be made with addition and subtraction, using all numbers given

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I've profiled my application, and it spends 90% of its time in `plus_minus_variations`.

The function finds ways to make various numbers given a list of numbers using addition and subtraction.

For example:
Input

```
1, 2
```

Output

```
1+2=3
1-2=-1
-1+2=1
-1-2=-3
```

This is my current code. I think it could be improved a lot in terms of speed.

```
def plus_minus_variations(nums):
    result = dict()
    for i, ops in zip(xrange(2 ** len(nums)), \
            itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=len(nums))):
        total = sum(map(operator.mul, ops, nums))
        result[total] = ops
    return result
```

I'm mainly looking for a different algorithm to approach this with. My current one seems pretty inefficient. However, if you have optimization suggestions about the code itself, I'd be happy to hear those too.

Additional:

- It's okay if the result is missing some of the answers (or has some extraneous answers) if it finishes a lot faster.
- **If there are multiple ways to get a number, any of them are fine.**
- For the list sizes I'm using, 99.9% of the ways produce duplicate numbers.
- It's okay if the result doesn't have the way that the numbers were produced, if, again, it finishes a lot faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be significantly faster for large random lists, I guess you could further micro-optimize it, but I prefer readability.

I chunk the list into smaller pieces and create variations for it. Since you get a lot less than `2 ** len(chunk)` variatons it's going to be faster. Chunk length is 6, you can play with it to see what's the optimal chunk length.

```
def pmv(nums):
    chunklen=6
    res = dict()
    res[0] = ()
    for i in xrange(0, len(nums), chunklen):
        part = plus_minus_variations(nums[i:i+chunklen])
        resnew = dict()
        for (i,j) in itertools.product(res, part):
            resnew[i + j] = tuple(list(res[i]) + list(part[j]))
        res = resnew
    return res
```

Comment: You made me to look through your suggestion once again :-) Well, +1.

Comment: Awesome, by using your chunking aproach, I reduced runtime of my function by a factor of 10^4.

Answer (score 6):

If it is ok not to get trace of number producing there is no reasons to recalculate sum of number combination every time. You can store intermediate results:

```
def combine(l,r):
    res = set()
    for x in l:
        for y in r:
            res.add( x+y )
            res.add( x-y )
            res.add( -x+y )
            res.add( -x-y )
    return list(res)

def pmv(nums):
    if len(nums) > 1:
        l = pmv( nums[:len(nums)/2] )
        r = pmv( nums[len(nums)/2:] )
        return combine( l, r )
    return nums
```

**EDIT**: if the way of number generation is important you can use this variant:

```
def combine(l,r):
    res = dict()
    for x,q in l.iteritems():
        for y,w in r.iteritems():
            if not res.has_key(x+y):
                res[x+y] = w+q
                res[-x-y] = [-i for i in res[x+y]]
            if not res.has_key(x-y):
                res[x-y] = w+[-i for i in q]
                res[-x+y] = [-i for i in res[x-y]]
    return res

def pmv(nums):
    if len(nums) > 1:
        l = pmv( nums[:len(nums)/2] )
        r = pmv( nums[len(nums)/2:] )
        return combine( l, r )
    return {nums[0]:[1]}
```

My tests shows that it is still faster than the other solutions.

Comment: This is very interesting and very fast! (+1)

Comment: what kind of test did you do? I've tested it and my solution seems to be 1.5-2.5 times faster. I'm using random integers between 0 and 200 in the input.

Comment: also, with agf's implementation and changing the magic constant in my code to 5 it's almost 4x faster.

Comment: @yi_H, I've tested it on a range(1,100). Time of my solution - 4.25308320829, yours - 6.89982147061. Now I've checked the range 0 to 200. Results are 80.2901003113 and 76.8834856788. So you win on this data, but your algorithm does not provide significant handicap on my computer.

Comment: test it with more than 18 elements.

Comment: @yi_H, Well, on range(0,100) all your tricks gave me 5.48353430452. Still there is no benefit. To be fair, on range(0,200) your result is 58.1099703820 and that is better than mine.

Comment: BTW, there are there are 100 elements in my original test, and most of initial solutions hung my computer for ages on that.

Comment: @Kabie: I don't have python3 here, and the python2 solution is sloooow.

Comment: @Kabie, updated code is really fast - 1.06979902454 on (0,200). But it does not provide any info about the way of number construction.

Comment: @tyz: wait a minute, you mean you are using range(0,100) as input? that's not really realistic. My mesaurements with random input show that mine is a lot faster for any input length >= 20. Python 2.6 here. Example: 55 random elements in range(0,200). mine: 3.11, yours: 12.12

Comment: @yi_H: You can run it on Python 2, the difference is tiny.

Comment: @yi_H: results on your example: mine - 4.41429723379, yours - 5.11999189144. It seems to be significantly system-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED:**

Aha!
Code is in Python 3,
inspired by tyz:

```
from functools import reduce # only in Python 3

def process(old, num):
    new = set(map(num.__add__, old)) # use itertools.imap for Python 2
    new.update(map((-num).__add__, old))
    return new

def pmv(nums):
    n = iter(nums)
    x = next(n)
    result = {x, -x} # set([x, -x]) for Python 2
    return reduce(process, n, result)
```

Instead of split half and recursive, I use `reduce` to compute it one by one. that extremely reduced the times of function calls.

Take less than 1 sec to compute 256 numbers.

---

Why product then mult?

```
def pmv(nums):
    return {sum(i):i for i in itertools.product(*((num, -num) for num in nums))}
```

Can be faster without how the numbers were produced:

```
def pmv(nums):
    return set(map(sum, itertools.product(*((num, -num) for num in nums))))
```

Comment: and even faster with `itertools.imap`; nice!

Comment: Also do `from itertools import product` and I think the second one is as fast as possible, the first one would be faster wth a normal loop instead of a dict comprehension, at least for me on Windows with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can get something like a 50% speedup (at least for short lists) just by doing:

```
from itertools import product, imap
from operator import mul

def plus_minus_variations(nums):
    result = {}
    for ops in product((-1, 1), repeat=len(nums)):
        result[sum(imap(mul, ops, nums))] = ops
    return result
```

`imap` won't create intermediate lists you don't need. Importing into the local namespace saves the time attribute lookup takes. Tuples are faster than lists. Don't store unneeded intermediate items.

I tried this with a dict comprehension but it was a bit slower. I tried it with a set comprehension (not saving the `ops`) and it was the same speed.

I don't know why you were using `zip` and `xrange` at all... you weren't using the result in your calculation.

Edit: I get significant speedups with this version all the way up to the point where your version gives a memory error, not just for short lists.

Comment: Re: "I tried this with a dict comprehension..." -- meaning this? `def plus_minus_variations(nums):\n
    return dict(\n
        (sum(imap(mul, ops, nums)), ops)\n
        for ops in product((-1, 1), repeat=len(nums))\n
    )\n
`

Comment: A dict comprehension is Python 2.7 / 3.2 syntactic sugar for that, `{sum(imap(mul, ops, nums)): ops for ops in product((-1, 1), repeat = len(nums))}`

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematical point of view you finally arive at all multiples of the greatest common divisor of your startvalues.

For example:

- startvalues 2,4. then the gcd(2,4) is 2, so the generated numbers are .. -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, ...
- startvalues 3,5. then the gcd(3,5) is 1, you get all integers.
- startvalues 12, 18, 15. the gcd(12,15,18) is 3, you get .. -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, ....

Comment: nice point, but you can't use a number more than once, so you get finite numbers of results.

Answer (score 0):

This simple iterative method computes all possible sums. It could be about 5 times faster than the recursive method by @tyz.

```
def pmv(nums):
    sums = set()
    sums.add(0)
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        partialsums = set()
        for s in sums:
            partialsums.add(s + nums[i])
            partialsums.add(s - nums[i])
        sums = partialsums
    return sums
```